# Linux wget file output

Tags: linux, unix, sed, wget

I'm a total Linux noob. I just want to append a field in the first column
Ex. 192.168.0.254 mwd.com

```
wget -O - "http://mirror1.malwaredomains.com/files/justdomains" | ??? > /var/hosts.md
```

I was thinking to use sed but there's no data to substitute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can substitute with a beginning-of-line or end-of-line marker:

```
> echo line | sed -e 's/$/ foobar/'
line foobar
> echo line | sed -e 's/^/foobar /'
foobar line
```

Answer (score 2):

you can still use sed, just match on the start of line:

```
wget -O - "http://mirror1.malwaredomains.com/files/justdomains" | sed 's/^/192.168.0.254 /' >/var/hosts.md
```